# Cut off values of the coefficient of variation in determining whether to include/exclude a sample

Tags: coefficient-of-variation

I'm fairly new to statistics and could use some advice.

I have 70 blood serum samples that have had metabolite concentrations tested twice. (Same blood draw, different test dates). I calculated the average, the standard deviation and the coefficient of variation as a percentage for each sample's two measurements. Then I calculated the average %CV of all 70 samples. The average %CV is less than 10%, which according to what I've read is acceptable, but some of the individual %CV's are much higher.

In this case you would expect to see some variation between tests, but a large difference would be indicative of some error in handling the specimen. I'm trying to determine a cut off value over which to reject the sample. The %CV's are not normally distributed (according to Shapiro-Wilks) or else I would say + 2 std.dev. Is there a mathematical way to determine an appropriate cut off?

Thanks!

Comment: There actually are environmental regulations and guidance prescribing laboratory data quality objectives in these terms, so I would expect comparable regulations to apply to medical laboratories. What kinds of QA/QC procedures does your lab follow and what is its guidance about this?

Comment: The tests were preformed at an outside lab. I've emailed them for their input, but I wanted to understand the theory behind the cutoffs rather than just be told what they are.

Comment: As far as regulations go, there's no statistical theory at all behind it: the cutoffs are based on the accuracy the agencies think they need.